# Pip can't upgrade a built-in package in ubuntu 15.04

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, pip

I no longer seem to be able to upgrade a package already installed in Ubuntu 15.04. Pip still works, installing the package into `/usr/local/python2.7/dist-packages`, but the path lists `/usr/python2.7/dist-packages` at the top, and even `PYTHONPATH` can't get something above that line. I believe this works in older Ubuntus. I've been trying to find something in `/usr/python/site.py`, but it seems to do the right thing. Adding `-S` does seem to stop the non-local version from being at the top. I've seen this on two computers, I believe.

Some examples of the need for this: Updating to get a required feature/bugfix (for PILLOW, in my case) without APT uninstalling a bunch of packages that list that package as a requirement.

Edit:
For clarification, the question is: I want to reorder the directory search order to recover Ubuntu 14.10 behavior. There are better ways to do this on many systems, but I want to use the built in apt packaging, just with one or two (potential) newer packages, like IPython and the like, rather than use virtual-env and Anacoda (both of which I use on other systems). It looks like my desired behavior is the documented Debian behavior, so I'm not sure why it's reordering the path.

Here's the path to demonstrate the problem, notice the `PYTHONPATH` variable is in the middle, with two git folders:

```
>>> sys.path
['',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', 
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-2.6.0-py2.7.egg', 
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/octave_kernel-0.10.0-py2.7.egg',
'/home/username/git/maya',
'/home/username/git/udaq/pyUDAQ',
'/usr/lib/python2.7',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', 
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
'/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2']
```

For reference, I have a matching system running 14.04, and it has exactly the expected behavior. The two `PYTHONPATH` dirs come first, then then later on the local `dist-packages` are above the built in.

Comment: I think letting `pip` and `apt` fight over packages is a very bad idea. A much cleaner way would be to switch to `virtualenvs` instead.

Comment: I want to be able to hand my computer to someone who follows directions but doesn't know much. Telling him "ipython notebook" is easier than having to tell him to activate a virtual env first. That's generally a good idea, though.

Comment: In that case: switch to `anaconda` and install the packages into the root environment. Then `conda` and `pip` are now your package managers and `apt` won't interfere.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [`-t` switch](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#cmdoption-t) in pip. It allows you to configure a directory where pip installs packages.

You can set the directory in a [config file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#config-file) and forget about specifying it each time you install or upgrade packages

But generally it is a bad idea to upgrade packages installed by `apt`

Comment: I don't want to bulldoze the packages in `/usr/python`, I just want to make `/usr/local/python` searched first. Thanks though!

Comment: @HenrySchreiner Ok, but then I am surprised, because paths from `PYTHONPATH` will be added to `sys.path` before standard interpreter paths. Can you update your post with more information? How do you modify `PYTHONPATH` and what does `print sys.path` output?

Comment: @HenrySchreiner [relevant documentation link](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)

Comment: I'll do that as soon as I get internet access again (possibly tomorrow). Basically, the top 4-6 lines are above even `PYTHONPATH` entries, tested by putting something silly in PYTHONPATH then looking at the location of the entry in sys.path.

Answer (score 2):

Use **virtualenv**:

install virtualenv

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
```

create environment in MYENV directory

```
$ virtualenv MYENV
```

activate environment in current shell (your app will need this as well on it's startup script)

```
$ . MYENV/bin/activate
```

use pip/python from your venv located in MYENV directory (you own)

```
(MYENV)$ pip ...
```

Comment: If you're on ubuntu and 16.04 or newer, you'll probably want `sudo apt-get install virtualenv` instead of `python-virtualenv`